# SnowFlake/SnowSQL: Compilation Scripts

Tags: snowflake, snowsql

In Oracle/Postgres it is possible to write a script that will run other scripts/files such as

compile_script.sql (contains)
@script1.sql
@script2.sql
@script3.sql

When you run compile_script.sql it runs all three of those scripts.

In snowSQL (command line tool for SnowFlake) you can run the sql in a file with a !source compile_script.sql but I am unable to determine how I can have that run other files as I can do in Oracle/Postgres.

How would I go about running all of or part of the scripts in a directory without having to run each of them by hand?